# How to return a char** in C

Tags: c

I've been trying for a while now and I can not seem to get this working:

```
char** fetch  (char *lat, char*lon){
  char emps[10][50];
  //char** array = emps;
  int cnt = -1;

  while (row = mysql_fetch_row(result)) 
  { 
    char emp_det[3][20];
    char temp_emp[50] = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        strcpy(emp_det[i], row[i]);
    }

    if ( (strncmp(emp_det[1], lat, 7) == 0) && (strncmp(emp_det[2], lon, 8) == 0) ) {

        cnt++;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            strcat(temp_emp, emp_det[i]);
            if(i < 3) {     
                strcat(temp_emp, " ");
            }   
        }
        strcpy(emps[cnt], temp_emp);
    }
  }
}

mysql_free_result(result);
mysql_close(connection);
return array;
```

Yes, I know array = emps is commented out, but without it commented, it tells me that the pointer types are incompatible. This, in case I forgot to mention, is in a char** type function and I want it to return emps[10][50] or the next best thing. How can I go about doing that? Thank you!

Comment: Please show the *full* function, including the parameters and return type.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: `char emp_det[3][20];` needs **4** elements in its first dimension if you are indexing it with `emp_det[3]` as you do in the `i` loop.

Comment: Let apart this is an automatic variable, a pointer is not an array! `char **` is a very different type than `char[R][C]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're attempting won't work, even if you attempt to cast, because you'll be returning the address of a local variable.  When the function returns, that variable goes out of scope and the memory it was using is no longer valid.  Attempting to dereference that address will result in undefined behavior.

What you need is to use dynamic memory allocation to create the data structure you want to return:

```
char **emps;
emps = malloc(10 * sizeof(char *));
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    emps[i] = malloc(50);
}
....
return emps;
```

The calling function will need to `free` the memory created by this function.  It also needs to know how many allocations were done so it knows how many times to call `free`.

Comment: Thank you! That seemed to help. I understood the problem now, with the local variable that will be inexistent to point to after the function is done. For some reason now, I get the whole row in the database, but that is still something more than I had.

Comment: Scratch that, running on no sleep. Didn't realize which code I put up lol. Thank you again

Answer (score 3):

An array expression of type `T [N][M]` *does not* decay to `T **` - it decays to type `T (*)[M]` (pointer to `M`-element array).

Secondly, you're trying to return the address of an array that's local to the function; once the function exits, the `emps` array *no longer exists*, and any pointer to it becomes invalid.

You'd probably be better off passing the target array as a parameter to the function and have the function write to it, rather than creating a new array within the function and returning it.  You could dynamically allocate the array, but then you're doing a memory management dance, and the best way to avoid problems with memory management is to avoid doing memory management.

So your function definition would look like

```
void fetch( char *lat, char *lon, char emps[][50], size_t rows ) { ... }
```

and your function call would look like

```
char my_emps[10][50];
...
fetch( &lat, &lon, my_emps, 10 );
```

Answer (score 2):

If you found a way to cast `char emps[10][50];` into a `char *` or `char **`

- you wouldn't be able to properly map the data (dimensions, etc). multi-dimensional char arrays are not `char **`. They're just contiguous memory with index calculation. Better fit to a `char *` BTW
- but the biggest problem would be that `emps` would go out of scope, and the auto memory would be reallocated to some other variable, destroying the data.

There's a way to do it, though, if your dimensions are *really* fixed:

You can create a function that takes a `char[10][50]` as an in/out parameter (you cannot return an array, not allowed by the compiler, you *could* return a struct containing an array, but that wouldn't be efficient)

Example:

```
void myfunc(char emp[10][50])
{
   emp[4][5] = 'a';  // update emp in the function

}

int main()
{
   char x[10][50];
   myfunc(x);
   // ...
}
```

The `main` program is responsible of the memory of `x` which is passed as modifiable to `myfunc` routine: it is safe and fast (no memory copy)

Good practice: define a type like this `typedef char matrix10_50[10][50];` it makes declarations more logical.

The main drawback here is that dimensions are fixed. If you want to use `myfunc` for another dimension set, you have to copy/paste it or use macros to define both (like a poor man's template).

#### EDIT

a fine comment suggests that some compilers support variable array size.
So you could pass dimensions alongside your unconstrained array:

`void myfunc(int rows, int cols, char emp[rows][cols])`

Tested, works with `gcc 4.9` (probably on earlier versions too) *only on C code*, not C++ and not in `.cpp` files containing plain C (but still beats cumbersome `malloc/free` calls)

Comment: I agree that it's best to pass the array to the function. If you have a compiler that supports [variable length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), you can declare the function as `void myfunc(int rows, int cols, char emp[rows][cols])` and then the array can be any size.

Comment: @user3386109: very interesting! but cannot seem to do it with gcc or even g++ -std=C++11. Do you have an example of compilers which can do that?

Comment: @user3386109 without invoking variable length arrays, some answer here avoids to pass the first dimension. Halfway :): `func(int rows, char emp[][50])`

Comment: Yup, that's a good answer too, but [gcc should work](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) .

Comment: Actually it works. It's just that I put my code in a file called `.cpp` and `gcc` silently switched to C++. Renamed to `.c` and it worked! Learning a lot tonight!

Answer (score 0):

In order to understand why you can't do that, you need to understand how matrices work in C.

A matrix, let's say your char emps[10][50] is a continuous block of storage capable of storing 10*50=500 chars (imagine an array of 500 elements). When you access emps[i][j], it accesses the element at index 50*i + j in that "array" (pick a piece of paper and a pen to understand why). The problem is that the 50 in that formula is the number of columns in the matrix, which is known at the compile time from the data type itself. When you have a char** the compiler has no way of knowing how to access a random element in the matrix.

A way of building the matrix such that it is a char** is to create an array of pointers to char and then allocate each of those pointers:

```
char **emps = malloc(10 * sizeof(char*)); // create an array of 10  pointers to char
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    emps[i] = malloc(50 * sizeof(char)); // create 10 arrays of 50 chars each
```

The point is, you can't convert a matrix to a double pointer in a similar way you convert an array to a pointer.

Answer (score -1):

Another problem: Returning a 2D matrix as 'char**' is only meaningful if the matrix is implemented using *an array of pointers*, each pointer pointing to *an array of characters*.  As explained previously, a 2D matrix in C is just a flat array of characters.  The most you can return is a pointer to the [0][0] entry, a 'char*'.  There's a mismatch in the number of indirections.

Comment: See @Olaf's answer.  You can return a char[R][C], but that is different from returning a char**.